# How to get time value from TimeZone?

Tags: java

I want to get time of the city I passed to the constructor. How can use TimeZone to get time from it and save that time value in a string variable time in City class.

```
package com.example.worldclocktest;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.UUID;

public class City implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean important;
    private String time;

    public City(String name){
        init();
        this.name = name;
        this.important = false;

        this.time = TimeZone.getTimeZone(name);
    }
    private void init() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setImportant(boolean val) {
        this.important = val;
    }
    public boolean isImportant() {
        return this.important;
    }
    public String getTime()
    {
        return time;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `getOffset()` or `getRawOffset()`?

Comment: I want to get time of the City and display it on Screen. How these can help to get time from timeZone?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current time, you could use this construction:

```
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(name); // 4exmpl: "Europe/Madrid"
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(timeZone.toZoneId());
    this.time = zdt; // result like: 2021-04-21T21:54:35.785186+02:00[Europe/Madrid]
```

//for time you could use DateTimeFormatter, for example ISO_LOCAL_TIME:
this.time = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME); //result: 21:54:35.785

Important thing:  timeZone string value (city name in your sample) must contain one of the predefined values (region/predefined city name)

Answer (score 0):

Time zone abbreviations do not match directly with city names. See [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). So it's probably wise te represent timezones separately from the city name.

A TimeZone represents a set of rules to determine an offset (usually in hours) from UTC (which has offset +00:00). The offset can change over time because of daylight saving (summer/winter time). The daylight saving rules can also change over the years, so you cannot make assumptions about the offset of a timezone at any given time. Luckily the JVM can do this for us:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class City {

    private String name;
    private ZoneId zoneId;

    public City(String name, String timeZone) {
        this.name = name;
        zoneId = ZoneId.of(timeZone);
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return String.format("It's %s in %s", OffsetDateTime.now(zoneId), name);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        City suva = new City("Suva", "Pacific/Fiji");
        System.out.println(suva.getTime());
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
It's 2021-04-22T08:29:03.095+12:00 in Suva
```

If you provide an unrecognized timeZone name then an exception will be thrown:

```
City rebelBase = new City("Rebel base", "Hoth");
System.out.println(rebelBase.getTime());
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: Hoth
    at java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getProvider(ZoneRulesProvider.java:272)
    at java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(ZoneRulesProvider.java:227)
    at java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)
    at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)
    at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:359)
```